# Problem with Postgresql efficiency on ubuntu server

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu

I have two identical DB on my virtual server and my pc.
I made dump db on server and then unpack it on my home pc
I noticed that the same query is executed in different times on my pc and server
on pc ~ 0.9 sec, on vps ~20 sec

```
Configeration of PC:
Core(TM) i7-13700K   3.40 GHz
128gb RAM
2tb ssd m2
```

```
Configeration of vps:
CPUs 4 10.4 GHz allocated
64gb RAM
2tb hdd
```

I understand that my disk is much faster than on vps and even if I install new ssd on vps I won't achieve 0.9 sec, but still it should be fast than 20 sec.

So I install 250gb ssd on vps, yhen move postgres cluster on it and nothing happend, same 20sec
then I changed postgresql.conf
I set:

```
shared_buffers = 16GB
huge_pages = on
work_mem = 300MB
maintenance_work_mem = 8GB
effective_io_concurrency = 200
random_page_cost = 1.0
effective_cache_size = 32GB
```

Also I changed kernel settings
I set

```
vm.nr_hugepages bases on system needs
kernel.shmmax=16777216
kernel.shmall=16777216
vm.swappiness=1
vm.overcommit_memory=2
```

Also I ran  pg_stat_reset() and ANALYZE on vps db
And interesting fact, that after pg_stat_reset() this query was executed in 2 sec, but then for the second and next times again 20 sec.

It means it is possible to execute query faster, but I don't understand how

query example:

```
select
y.node_id,
y.links
from (
select distinct
case when x.point_num = 1 then x.ref_node_id when x.point_num = x.max_p then x.non_ref_node_id end as node_id,
array_agg(distinct x.link_id) as links,
array_agg(distinct x.geom) as geoms

from (select lk.link_id,
     (ST_DumpPoints(lk.geom)).path[1] as point_num,
     ST_NPoints(lk.geom) as max_p,
     lk.ref_node_id,
     lk.non_ref_node_id,
     (ST_DumpPoints(lk.geom)).geom as geom
    from "Link" lk
      ) as x
where x.point_num = 1 or x.point_num = x.max_p
group by node_id
) as y
where array_length(y.geoms, 1) > 1
```

explain (analyze, buffers, settings) on PC

```
"Subquery Scan on y  (cost=195715818275.45..195715819491.81 rows=60818 width=40) (actual time=53749.993..53750.033 rows=0 loops=1)"
"  Buffers: shared hit=11625 read=594820, temp read=754031 written=755068"
"  ->  Unique  (cost=195715818275.45..195715818883.63 rows=60818 width=72) (actual time=53749.992..53750.032 rows=0 loops=1)"
"        Buffers: shared hit=11625 read=594820, temp read=754031 written=755068"
"        ->  Sort  (cost=195715818275.45..195715818427.50 rows=60818 width=72) (actual time=53749.991..53750.031 rows=0 loops=1)"
"              Sort Key: (CASE WHEN (x.point_num = 1) THEN x.ref_node_id WHEN (x.point_num = x.max_p) THEN x.non_ref_node_id ELSE NULL::bigint END), (array_agg(DISTINCT x.link_id)), (array_agg(DISTINCT x.geom))"
"              Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25kB"
"              Buffers: shared hit=11625 read=594820, temp read=754031 written=755068"
"              ->  GroupAggregate  (cost=195715805131.36..195715810947.29 rows=60818 width=72) (actual time=53749.985..53750.025 rows=0 loops=1)"
"                    Group Key: (CASE WHEN (x.point_num = 1) THEN x.ref_node_id WHEN (x.point_num = x.max_p) THEN x.non_ref_node_id ELSE NULL::bigint END)"
"                    Filter: (array_length(array_agg(DISTINCT x.geom), 1) > 1)"
"                    Rows Removed by Filter: 15073003"
"                    Buffers: shared hit=11625 read=594820, temp read=754031 written=755068"
"                    ->  Sort  (cost=195715805131.36..195715805597.06 rows=186278 width=48) (actual time=30583.674..32904.574 rows=37398936 loops=1)"
"                          Sort Key: (CASE WHEN (x.point_num = 1) THEN x.ref_node_id WHEN (x.point_num = x.max_p) THEN x.non_ref_node_id ELSE NULL::bigint END)"
"                          Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 2010792kB"
"                          Buffers: shared hit=11625 read=594820, temp read=754031 written=755068"
"                          ->  Subquery Scan on x  (cost=1000.00..195715783092.43 rows=186278 width=48) (actual time=0.412..19751.531 rows=37398936 loops=1)"
"                                Filter: ((x.point_num = 1) OR (x.point_num = x.max_p))"
"                                Rows Removed by Filter: 73240944"
"                                Buffers: shared hit=11625 read=594820"
"                                ->  Gather  (cost=1000.00..195715502043.18 rows=18674524 width=64) (actual time=0.411..14311.958 rows=110639880 loops=1)"
"                                      Workers Planned: 2"
"                                      Workers Launched: 2"
"                                      Buffers: shared hit=11625 read=594820"
"                                      ->  Result  (cost=0.00..195713633590.78 rows=7781052000 width=64) (actual time=0.296..13555.925 rows=36879960 loops=3)"
"                                            Buffers: shared hit=11625 read=594820"
"                                            ->  ProjectSet  (cost=0.00..136891570.78 rows=7781052000 width=177) (actual time=0.291..8554.085 rows=36879960 loops=3)"
"                                                  Buffers: shared hit=11625 read=594820"
"                                                  ->  Parallel Seq Scan on ""Link"" lk  (cost=0.00..684255.52 rows=7781052 width=145) (actual time=0.276..843.207 rows=6233156 loops=3)"
"                                                        Buffers: shared hit=11625 read=594820"
"Settings: search_path = '""$user"", public, tiger, topology'"
"Planning Time: 0.230 ms"
"Execution Time: 53838.300 ms"
```

explain (analyze, buffers, settings) on vps

```
"Subquery Scan on y  (cost=390643534813.38..390643536030.92 rows=60877 width=40) (actual time=302571.382..302584.406 rows=35 loops=1)"
"  Buffers: shared hit=36 read=615858, temp read=251588 written=251589"
"  ->  Unique  (cost=390643534813.38..390643535422.15 rows=60877 width=72) (actual time=302571.363..302584.367 rows=35 loops=1)"
"        Buffers: shared hit=36 read=615858, temp read=251588 written=251589"
"        ->  Sort  (cost=390643534813.38..390643534965.57 rows=60877 width=72) (actual time=302571.345..302575.100 rows=35 loops=1)"
"              Sort Key: (CASE WHEN (x.point_num = 1) THEN x.ref_node_id WHEN (x.point_num = x.max_p) THEN x.non_ref_node_id ELSE NULL::bigint END), (array_agg(DISTINCT x.link_id)), (array_agg(DISTINCT x.geom))"
"              Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 31kB"
"              Buffers: shared hit=36 read=615858, temp read=251588 written=251589"
"              ->  GroupAggregate  (cost=390643524154.35..390643529975.60 rows=60877 width=72) (actual time=208002.806..302574.125 rows=35 loops=1)"
"                    Group Key: (CASE WHEN (x.point_num = 1) THEN x.ref_node_id WHEN (x.point_num = x.max_p) THEN x.non_ref_node_id ELSE NULL::bigint END)"
"                    Filter: (array_length(array_agg(DISTINCT x.geom), 1) > 1)"
"                    Rows Removed by Filter: 15073476"
"                    Buffers: shared hit=28 read=615858, temp read=251588 written=251589"
"                    ->  Sort  (cost=390643524154.35..390643524620.41 rows=186424 width=48) (actual time=207912.909..215920.138 rows=37399512 loops=1)"
"                          Sort Key: (CASE WHEN (x.point_num = 1) THEN x.ref_node_id WHEN (x.point_num = x.max_p) THEN x.non_ref_node_id ELSE NULL::bigint END)"
"                          Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 2012704kB"
"                          Buffers: shared hit=19 read=615858, temp read=251588 written=251589"
"                          ->  Subquery Scan on x  (cost=1000.00..390643507834.58 rows=186424 width=48) (actual time=1159.748..161684.475 rows=37399512 loops=1)"
"                                Filter: ((x.point_num = 1) OR (x.point_num = x.max_p))"
"                                Rows Removed by Filter: 73242457"
"                                Buffers: shared hit=19 read=615858"
"                                ->  Gather  (cost=1000.00..390643226566.32 rows=18689076 width=64) (actual time=1159.744..139305.430 rows=110641969 loops=1)"
"                                      Workers Planned: 2"
"                                      Workers Launched: 2"
"                                      Buffers: shared hit=19 read=615858"
"                                      ->  Result  (cost=0.00..390641356658.72 rows=7787115000 width=64) (actual time=1090.274..90631.003 rows=36880656 loops=3)"
"                                            Buffers: shared hit=19 read=615858"
"                                            ->  ProjectSet  (cost=0.00..234346133.73 rows=7787115000 width=176) (actual time=1090.264..61234.001 rows=36880656 loops=3)"
"                                                  Buffers: shared hit=19 read=615858"
"                                                  ->  Parallel Seq Scan on ""Link"" lk  (cost=0.00..693748.15 rows=7787115 width=144) (actual time=6.453..10329.767 rows=6233252 loops=3)"
"                                                        Buffers: shared hit=19 read=615858"
"Settings: effective_cache_size = '32GB', effective_io_concurrency = '500', random_page_cost = '1', work_mem = '2GB'"
"Planning:"
"  Buffers: shared hit=188"
"Planning Time: 0.938 ms"
"JIT:"
"  Functions: 44"
"  Options: Inlining true, Optimization true, Expressions true, Deforming true"
"  Timing: Generation 9.531 ms, Inlining 524.496 ms, Optimization 1881.259 ms, Emission 843.753 ms, Total 3259.039 ms"
"Execution Time: 304232.738 ms"
```

Comment: Making random changes that you don't understand is unlikely to help and if it does it will be by accident. First you need to understand why the query is slow on your vps. If it is a specific query that is causing you problems then begin by posting the query and the output of `EXPLAIN ANALYSE` with that query. If it is a problem with most queries then you need to start by taking basic performance measurements of the vps and identifying the bottleneck.

Comment: First of all, I did not make any random changes, I've read a lot about tuning postgresql on linux and made it based on reccomendations. Second, the problem is about all queries on vps. And I saw that the query I tested on can be executed in 2 sec, so the question is how to achieve is on regular basis

Comment: OK, so `pg_stat_reset` is just dealing with the monitoring stats (number of reads on each table / index etc) and is nothing to do with query planning or execution. Any change in query performance after calling that is clearly just coincidence. Random. If it is all queries then you need to (repeatedly) measure some actual performance figures (cpu, disk, network) on the vps, compare those to your local machine and then ask about wherever they differ.

Comment: You keep speaking about "the query": how about editing the question and showing the query, as well as the `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS, SETTINGS)` output on both the slow and the fast system?

Comment: The query I talked about is quite complex and long and Explain is long too so I attached another example.  work_mem parameter is different compare with I mentioned in question because I'm playing with it right now

Comment: But again, it's not about comparing two machines. If some query can be executed in 2sec and then the same query in 20 sec for all other times and there are no any other processes that can affect on efficiency. I assume it's not about bottleneck but about wrong settings resource allocation

Comment: In the plans you showed us, there is a large timing difference in the bottom level seq scan.  This is probably a difference in IO.  If you set track_io_timing to on, then the plan should show you explicitly what the IO timing is, to confirm this.

Comment: The pg_stat_reset() things sounds interesting, but without plans that pertain to it there is nothing we can do but throw darts blindly.